# How do clean_class and clean_id work?

Tags: 8, theming

I am new to Drupal 8 and Twig syntax. I am not able to understand how the *clean_class* filter works in `region|clean_class`. What is *clean_class*? I have added the following code in the page.html.twig file.

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'region',
    'region-' ~ region|clean_class,
  ]
%}
    
{{ dump(classes) }}
```

It prints this.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'region' (length=6)
  1 => string 'region-' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`clean_class` is a filter which invokes the `\Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::getClass()` method on the string, which:

> Prepares a string for use as a valid class name.

Basically it removes invalid characters from HTML classes in preparation for rendering. `clean_id` is the equivalent for HTML IDs.

There are other filters registered by core too, see [TwigExtension::getFilters](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Template!TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3AgetFilters/8) for more details.

Comment: It looks like in the OP's example, region|clean_class isn't returning anything because the two resulting classes in {{ dump(classes) }} are 'region' and 'region-'

I'm currently having the same problem trying to add a taxonomy term name to the id using attributes.setAttribute('id', 'featured-industry-' ~ name|clean_id)

If I remove the |clean_id filter, it just prints 'Array'